# How to read an array field of a particular document id from firebase in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

how can I read array for a particular document id(string)? As we can see that "documents[0].data['cites'].length" in that code integer parameter was passing in documents but if I want to pass string document id then what my code should be?

my database structure is given bellow
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1EnV.png)

Answer (score 0):

you can use a for loop:

```dart
for(final doc in documents) {
  if(doc.id == 'your_doc_id'){
    //do your stuff here
  }
}
```

or you can use the where of filter methods from List:

```dart
final myDoc = documents.where((doc) => doc.id == 'your_document_id').first;
```